# Remove child node error

Tags: javascript

I am having problems with the code below, i keep getting this error in Opera:

```
Uncaught exception: DOMException: NOT_FOUND_ERR
```

And this in Chrome:

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
```

This messages refers to removeInput function:

```
function addInput() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var txt = "<div>Upload image: <input type='file' name='slika[]' /> <span onclick='removeInput(this.parentNode)' />Remove <img src='catalog/remove_icon.png' /></span></div>";
  div.innerHTML = txt;
  document.getElementById('text').appendChild(div);
}

function removeInput(el) {
  document.getElementById('text').removeChild(el);
}
```

Question is: how to remove element previosly created by addInput function? Is this right way to remove element dynamicaly?

Comment: Look at function addInput (if that is thing you ask me for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`el.parentNode.removeChild(el);`

Comment: Oh, sure, i didnt had the time to wait (there was something like 2 mins until i can mark answer as correct), now it's marked :) Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

for first: you dont need to write "`<div>`" in innerHTML, because createElement creates "`<div></div>`" by default.

for second: if you want to delete last inserted element, you need to save it after insert in global variable

```
var lastInserted = null;
function addInput() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var txt = "Upload image: <input type='file' name='slika[]' /> <span onclick='removeInput(this.parentNode)' />Remove <img src='catalog/remove_icon.png' /></span>";
  div.innerHTML = txt;
  document.getElementById('text').appendChild(div);
  lastInserted = div;
}

function removeInput() {
  if(!lastInserted)return;
  document.getElementById('text').removeChild(lastInserted);
}
```

Comment: Not just last inserted element, but any inserted element.